# C# Selenium javascript to remove element does not work

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to check a checkbox that is being obstructed by another element.

I tried to remove the element by javascript, but selenium still says it is obstructed. I also checked the source of the page after the javascript is executed and the element is still there. Am I doing something wrong?

```cs
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName('ins')[0].remove();");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='order_terms']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return word. Try the below code

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("return.document.getElementsByTagName('ins')[0].remove();");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='order_terms']")).Click();
```